# Batch Compress Videos with ffmpeg

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, compression, mp4

I have many videos in a folder, and I want to compress them all with one command.

To compress one video I use:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.mp4
```

But what if I have many videos I want to compress?
I've tried the following:

```
ffmpeg -i ./videos ./compressed-videos
```

But then I get this error:

```
./videos: Is a directory
```

Comment: Did you try [`find` with `-exec`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/227671/209677)?

Comment: No I didn't, could you provide an example. Because I don't know what I should pass as ffmpet input :)

Comment: See [How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33766147/1109017)

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly!

Comment: Does this affect quality at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use bash `for` loop for this purpose - let's assume you are in the parent directory, that contains the directories `videos/` and `compressed/`:

```bsh
for f in videos/*mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" "compressed/${f##*/}"; done
```

Or if you want to convert any type of video file to mkv, you can use:

```bsh
for f in videos/*; do ffmpeg -i "$f" "compressed/$(basename "${f%.*}").mkv"; done
```

In the above examples:

- `${var##*/}` will outputs all characters after the last slash `/`, so only the filename without the path will remains;
- `${f%.*}` will outputs all characters before the last dot, so the path and the filename will be kept but the file extension will be removed. Then the command substitution `$(basename "/path/name")` will outputs only the name without the path.

References:

- [How do I remove the file suffix and path portion from a path string in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/125340/6543935)
- [How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5784661/6543935)

Comment: Anyway to do this at the same time? We want to split up and use all the cores.

Comment: Hello, @OliverDixon. You can use something like `nohup ffmpeg ... >/tmp/${var##*/}.log 2>&1 &` to run each `ffmpeg` command in a detached shell, then you can monitor the progress of each by the created log. Here is an references: https://askubuntu.com/a/1192383/566421